# How to change a git repo to a git flow repo

Tags: git, git-flow

If I already have a git repo, how can I change it to a git flow style repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git flow init` from the repo folder, just like you do with `git init`.

I would recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/FAQ